# How to block a particular IP from making requests to my EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services

there is a bot that keeps searching for security vulnerabilities my site and ended up ddosing me like 4 times per day.

I want to block this IP 31.220.61.65

My architecture is very simple:
I have one EC2 instance with elastic IP serving a website. (of course it has a security group attached as well allowing port 443)

Every couple of hours the ip above (and others) make like 300 requests per minute and crash my modest server and leave tthe real users without service.

How can I block requests from particular ips reaching the ec2 in my simple architecture?

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/820869/aws-ec2-deny-single-ip-address-and-allow-all

Answer (score 3):

You can [use Network ACLs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-block-or-allow-ips/)

If your EC2 instance is behind a load balancer or CloudFront distribution you can add a [Web Application Firewall](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) and block the IP via a WAF rule.

Comment: The ec2 is not behind CloudFront or a Web Application Firewall. The website static ip (elastic ip) is directly attached to the ec2 and accessed from the clients

Comment: Then an inbound NACL rule is your only option.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest and quickest way to block IPs for such attacks is to block them at NACL level.

1. Go to the subnet of your EC2 instance
2. Select NetworkACL as shown in below picture
3. Click on the highlighted link to go on NACL detail page
4. Add a Deny Rule for IP `31.220.61.65/32`.

### Locate the Network ACL for EC2

[image]

### Add Deny rule to block IP

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment but it does not work, `The source needs to be an IPv4 or IPv6 CIDR block.
` I think have to put /32 to the `Source` field or ? It is a CIDR block not a single ip..

Comment: You're right, if it is a single IP then you have to append /32 else the CIDR.